# HTTPServer / FTPServer loop colliding with callback thread

Tags: gpio, python, networking, web-server, gpiozero

I am building an alarm application. I have a few PIR sensors and webcams.

The application contains a webserver I use to manage the alarm from a mobile application done with kivy.The webcams upload video/images via FTP.

The giozero functions/callbacks, the ftp server and the webserver all live in the same script.

The issue is, ftp server and web server coexist happily in the same script, however, the gpio callbacks will not work if the ftp server or the webserver are instantiated.

The web server and ftp server run on a separate thread while the main thread manages the GPIO pins.

I wonder if there is bad on my side  or any incompatibility  that I missed in the documentation.

Here  is a stub that reproduces the error.  "my_call" never gets called.

Would I better off using a different library

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python3

from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler
from http.server import HTTPServer
from urllib import parse
from urllib.parse import urlencode
import ssl

from pyftpdlib.authorizers import DummyAuthorizer
from pyftpdlib.handlers import FTPHandler
from pyftpdlib.servers import FTPServer

import threading
import datetime
import time
import sys
import logging
import json
import signal

from gpiozero import MotionSensor
from gpiozero import LED

serverip='192.168.33.220'
puerto=8080

ftpdir='/tmp'

def https(alarma):
    class GetHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):    
        def do_GET(self):
            parsed_path = parse.urlparse(self.path)            
            print(parsed_path)

            self.send_response(200)    
            self.send_header('Content-Type', 'text/plain; charset=utf-8')
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write("OK GOT IT".encode("utf-8"))
            alarma.retval=1

    server = HTTPServer((serverip, puerto), GetHandler)
    server.socket = ssl.wrap_socket (server.socket, 
                                     keyfile="../71407457_www.example.com.key", 
                                     certfile='../71407457_www.example.com.cert', server_side=True)

    threading.Thread(target=server.serve_forever).start()
    return server

class MyHandler(FTPHandler):

        def on_connect(self):
            print(self.remote_ip)


def ftpserver(alarma):

    authorizer = DummyAuthorizer()
    authorizer.add_user('user', '1234', ftpdir, perm='wme')

    handler = MyHandler
    handler.authorizer = authorizer

    handler.banner = " : "
    handler.alarma=alarma

    address = ('', 2121)
    server = FTPServer(address, handler)

    threading.Thread(target=server.serve_forever).start()
    return server

def mycall(channel):
    print(channel)

class alarma():
 def __init__(self,pin):

        sensor=MotionSensor(pin)
        sensor.when_motion=mycall

def main():


    a=alarma(19) 
    serverhttps=https(a)
    serverftp=ftpserver(a)  

    while True:
        signal.pause()

if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Comment: Does it work when you comment out "serverhttps=ftpserver(a)"? If so, please provide any insight into any error messages that may have resulted from that call.

Comment: sorry, yes that is a copy/paste typo. I will edit the code.  I wish I had an error message. It just silently object to call the callback function. so I do not know where to look.

Comment: sorry, yes that is a copy/paste typo. I will edit the code.  I wish I had an error message. It just silently object to call the callback/dispatch function. It is even more weird. In the real code I do a bunch of things, open files with context manager, logging, call a dispatch function and it does not work. I have changed the code to make the dispatch  via REST/API ( webserver running in the script, the service dispatch is available).....and now it works.....I was suspicious on how handler = MyHandler is instantiated...I do not understand the instantiation

Comment: Glad you solved your problem. You could post your solution and accept it for future folks

Comment: it's not a solution but a workaround.....and yet I do not understand yet why it works. I have the suspicion, after some diving into the gpiozero and ftpserverlib source code, that it's something related to interactions with the asyncio loop...thought I do not have the skills to fully grasp it. I eventually resorted to a workaround that at least I do understand how/why it works. I put the ftpserver in a separate process, rather than a separate thread (via multiprocessing module). I am still eager to learn if my issues arise from a feature or a bug.